# Why is the list $1,z,...,z^m$ linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ (for $m \in \mathbb{N}$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an assertion made in Axlers *Linear Algebra Done Right* (2.18(d) in Chapter 2).

$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ of course is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}$ is used to represent either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Let's say our list has two vectors so it's $1,z$. 
Let's choose the polynomials $p_a(x) = 1$ and $p_b(x) = (-1)$ from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$. 
Then $p_a(1) + p_b(z) = 1 - 1 = 0$ however obviously we've found coefficients $p_a,p_b$ which weren't both $0$ (or rather found polynomials with non-zero coefficients), thus not falling under the definition of linear independence.

Why is this not a valid counterexample to the assertion?

(I'm picking this up after a long break, so I'm probably overlooking something obvious)

Comment: You only have shown that $p_a(x)$ is the opposite of $p_b(x)$. What you are looking for (to show that $1,z$ are lineairly dependent, are coefficients $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ in F such that $\lambda_1 +$\lambda_2 z =0$. You'll find that this is the case if both coefficients are zero (and only in that case). Therefore, 1 and z are lineairly independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a valid counterexample to the assertion because you have not exhibited values $a_0,\dots,a_m \in \mathbb{F}$ (not all zero) such that 
$$a_0 \cdot 1 + a_1 \cdot z + \dots + a_m \cdot z^m = 0.$$
That is what it means for them to fail to be linearly independent. You have showed that $1$ and $-1$ are not linearly independent.